# Spring MVC binding nested list with checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, jsp, checkbox, jstl

I have a class User which has a list of objects Roles:

```
   public class User{

    List<Role> roles;
    ...
```

Role class has following properties:

```
    public class Role{

    private int id;
    private String shortcut;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    ...
```

In my controller I have a full list of roles that I pass to the JSP file. 
In JSP file I want to create a new user using form with checkboxes to the roles.
The role should be added to the list of roles if the appropriate checkbox is checked.

Following code doesn't work:

```
<form:form method="post" action="users/add"
name="addForm" modelAttribute="newUser">

    <c:forEach items="${listOfRoles}" var="r">
        <form:checkbox path="roles" value="${r}"
                    label="${r.name}" />
    </c:forEach>

<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" />
```

I have a model attribute "newUser" that contains list of objects called "roles". After submiting the form I want to have in that list objects(checkboxes) that were checked.

Method in the controller to handle the form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public final String addNewUser(@ModelAttribute User newUser, final BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

    } else {
        persistence.addUser(newUser);
    }
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Be more specific than "doesn't work". We also need the controller code.

Comment: first of all the name `user` (controller mehtod) and `newUser` (form) does not match!